# idiomatic way to check if array contains ordered (but possibly non-continuous) set of elements

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to get the functionality represented by the code below. Basically I just want to check if the array contains the elements in `pattern` in the order specified by `pattern`. It's okay for there to be gaps between these elements.

```
class Array
  def has_pattern?(pattern)
    offset = 0
    pattern.each do |p|
      offset = self[offset..-1].index(p)
      return false if offset.nil?
    end
    return true
  end
end

puts [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1].has_pattern?([1, 4, 5]) # true
puts [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1].has_pattern?([2, 3, 1]) # true
puts [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1].has_pattern?([1, 3, 2]) # false
```

The code above seems to work, but doesn't feel like idiomatic Ruby to me. Is there a nicer way to write this?

Comment: Not particularly, no. The algorithm you've written is quite nice. I'm sure there are other ways to do it but they won't be nearly as efficient as what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take on it:

```
class Array
  def has_pattern?(ptn)
    i = 0
    self.each do |elem|
      i += 1 if elem == ptn[i]
    end
    i >= ptn.size
  end
end
```

It passes through the array only once, so it may make a difference when the array's big.

Comment: This has the potentially undesirable side-effect of modifying the pattern object passed (by reference) by the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different way to approach it:

```
class Array
  def has_pattern?(pattern)
    (self - (self - pattern))
      .each_cons(pattern.length)
      .any? { |p| p === pattern }
  end
end
```

But, as I said in the comments above, I think your solution is superior.

Comment: It gives an incorrect answer for `[1,2,2,2,3].has_pattern? [1,2,3]`

Comment: @michau Ah, those pesky set operators and their tendency to de-dup. Let me see if I can fix it.

Comment: @michau Hrrm, are you sure? I show it returning false, which I believe is correct per the OP.

Comment: The array contains 1, 2, 3, in this order (with a gap). Why should it return false?

Comment: Ah, senior moment. Good catch. I think sticking a uniq in there after the set operation solves that problem, but then it can't take patterns with repeats. This may just be a bad solution.